# Change flutter end of widget comment colour

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, themes

I'm using VSC to create flutter apps and I find the end of widget comment too dominant (I use the quiet light theme). Is there any way to change the color of this comment to a lighter grey?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Dart-code has a special key `dart.closingLabels` to customize themed color.
Add the following snippet to `settings.json` :

```
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "[Default Dark+]": {
      "dart.closingLabels": "#335566"
    }
  }
```

My theme is Dark+, use another color for yuor theme with key `"[Quiet Light]"`.

Comment: can we add margin to it? i mean i want to indent these closing labels towards the end of screen so that code can look bit cleaner.

Comment: various colour code formats are supported `#RGB`, `#RGBA`, `#RRGGBB`, `#RRGGBBAA` ("A" is for "alpha"/opacity).